# How to fill an existing offer on the XRPL?

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, websocket, xrp

I am trying to create an offer that will match an existing one to exchange some tokens.

Even if the values are perfectly matching, I receive a tecKILLED result.. why ?

You will see the details in the screenshot below

[-> OfferCreate Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE70L.png)